# Checkbox Activity is not Performed in android

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment

I am going to made an application in which i use tab-view.
for each tab I'm using a fragment,but when I'm going to perform any activity, no activity is performed.

```
public class Tab_1_Activity extends Fragment {
   CheckBox Sunday_evening,Monday_morning,Monday_evening,Tuesday_morning,Tuesday_evening;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);

       Sunday_evening =(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.check_sunday_evening);
       Monday_morning =(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.check_monday_morning);
       Monday_evening =(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.check_monday_evening);
       Tuesday_morning=(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.check_tuesday_morning);
       Tuesday_evening= (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.check_tuesday_evening);

       //Monday Morning Checked condition

       Monday_morning.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
               if(b)
               {
                   Sunday_evening.setChecked(false);
                   Monday_evening.setChecked(false);
                   Tuesday_morning.setChecked(false);
                   Tuesday_evening.setChecked(false);
               }
               else
               {
                   Sunday_evening.setChecked(true);
                   Monday_evening.setChecked(true);
                   Tuesday_morning.setChecked(true);
                   Tuesday_evening.setChecked(true);
               }
           }
       });
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is ur actual problem. The above code  have nothing like to add a fragment to change the fragment or anything like that

Comment: if you get error then put logcat here

Comment: @VishalThakkar  no error in log cat when i run nothing performed checkbox condition on click.

Comment: @Nithinlal  I have use tab slider activity in that i used fragment in mainactivity after the layout pages create i have used  tab1,tab2 etc... in that called fragment

Comment: return rootView